# Calculating expected value under optimisation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, optimization, expected-value

I've been racking my brain over this problem which I was hoping to use basic probability and combinatorics. I cannot seem to find a similar solution to a sufficiently similar question either (though I am sure one exists somewhere).

The problem is as follows:

> Let's say I have 25 boxes.
>
> There are 5 boxes lablled A, 5 labelled B, 5 labelled C, 5 labelled D
> and 5 labelled E. I also have 25 balls of  five different colours - 5
> blue, 5 green, 5 red, 5 yellow and 5 purple. Balls are then randomly
> placed into a box (the box has no capacity constraints).
>
> A matrix is then created of the box letter and the number of balls of
> each colour (i.e., a 5 x 5 matrix). The columns of the matrix are rearranged in a way that maximises the sum of the  entries of the
> matrix on the main diagonal (note: there may be a better way of rearranging the matrix to
> obtain the highest accuracy, but I would like to keep it reasonably
> simple for now).
>
> *Note: @kodlu has kindly offered a much better term for this - maximising the trace of the matrix*
>
> Accuracy is then calculated as the sum of this diagonal divided by the
> sum of the elements in the matrix (i.e., 25).
>
> What is the expected value of the accuracy (and by extension, what is
> the expected value of the accuracy with n^2 boxes and n colours of
> balls)?

So far, my solution relies on the (incorrect) assumption that there are 5 balls in each box (which would make for a relatively straightforward binomial probability question). However, even in this case, I am not sure how to approach the effects of optimising the matrix.

Any leads / assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Update 1:**

To clarify what is meant by rearranging the diagonals, I have the following example (simplified).

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| Y | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| Z | 3 | 4 | 0 |

Then you could rewrite it as:

|  | B | C | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| Y | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Z | 4 | 0 | 3 |

In this case, one of the diagonals is (B,Z), (C,Y) and (A,X) which gives a total of 8.

Comment: "The matrix is rearranged such that the columns are rearranged in a way that maximises a diagonal of the matrix" What does this mean?

Comment: @AspiringMat sorry, I should have been a little clearer (I will update the original post shortly). Essentially if you had a really simple matrix like the following:
    A B C
X  1 0 2
Y  0 0 3
Z  3 4 0

Then you could rewrite it as:

    B C A
X  0 2 1
Y  0 3 0
Z  4 0 3

In this case, one of the diagonals is (B,Z), (C,Y) and (A,X) which gives a total of 8

Comment: you could say you want to maximize the trace of either the matrix or its transpose.